# jQuery скрипт не работает

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт:

```
while ($result= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print '<div class="friendList-ask">
               <a class="btn-main" href="#">Done</a>
           </div>';
}
```

Данный HTML код попадает на страницу с помощью `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php',
    success: function (data) {
            $('.userList').html(data);
            }
})
```

Проблема в том что после попадания данного кода на страницу, к нему не получается обратиться с помощью `jQuery`:

```
$(".friendList-ask .btn-main").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Hello");
})
```

Тоесть данный код не работает. `jQuery` скрипт не находит его.

**В чем же проблема? Как ее решить?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это класическая тема, на момент выполения скрипта

```
$(".friendList-ask .btn-main").on("click", function () {
```

элемент .friendList-ask .btn-main не существует, событие привязать не к чему.

Нужно использовать всплытие событий и закрепить его на внешнем постоянном враппере над .friendList-ask или на document,вот так:

```
$(document).on("click", ".friendList-ask .btn-main", function(){ .....  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Если событие на вновь созданном элементе, которого изначально не было - должна быть привязка к уже существующему элементу, который точно не изменится.

```
 $('#container_body').on('click', '.friendList-ask .btn-main', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hello");
    });
```